# How to loop certain lines in a text file via starting conditions?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am trying to solve a coding problem in python, and my pseudocode looks as follows:

```
x = 0
for line[x] in file:
    if line[x].startswith('>'): 
        next(line)
    while line[x] in file # !startwith('>'): do thing
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to skip any lines that start with '>', then for every line after I want to do a thing until the next line starts with a '>'.

I've looked up this question, and other questions I've seen don't talk about the startswith function, and instead talk about using readline() to pull out certain lines. Which is not what I am wanting to do. Can someone point me in a good direction to look?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, plead read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We cannot "point you in a direction", and we need a more concrete question than this. You should *try to write the actual code*, and then explain where you get stuck - by showing exactly what should happen, exactly what does happen instead, exactly how that's different, and by making it possible for others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want to talk about having "looked up this question", then you should show something concrete that you found, and explain how it failed to answer your question. We can only speculate as to why "other questions" (which ones?) "don't talk about" `.startswith`, but the most obvious reason is that the *specific* question they're addressing *doesn't involve* figuring out whether a string starts with some prefix. Your *specific* question clearly does, since you want to skip lines *that start with* `>`.

Comment: Also, please only tag things that are specific to the problem. The `bioinformatics` tag might make sense if your file is in a standard format that is used by people who do bioinformatics - but in that case, your *actual question* is about how to parse that file format, and you should start by looking for tools specific to that task (we don't recommend tools or libraries here).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This is FASTA format hence the bioinformatics tag

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in bioinformatics terms? Create a minimal, reproducible example with inputs, outputs etc.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I thought it might be. I added the tag back, but the question really should be asked in those terms. There seems to be an XY problem here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I will keep this in mind for future questions, thank you.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, I am doing a Rosalind challenge for bioinformatics. It is the FASTA format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your first mistake is indexing while in a for loop. You can simply read in a text file, and then loop over each line in it.

In your case, you would want to check that the first char of each line, and based on it's value apply logic to it.

```
with open("some_file.txt") as f: # opens a text file 
    for line in f:               # loops over each line 
        if line[0] == ">":       # check first char of line
            pass
        else:
             < do something >
```

Comment: Excellent awsome response

Comment: Oh, the indexing is what threw me off. Thank you, this is what I was looking for.